# WordCamp Phoenix

Tags: discussion

Today, all day, I'll be at [WordCamp Phoenix in Arizona](http://2012.phoenix.wordcamp.org/schedule/saturday/).  If there's anything you'd like me to ask speakers directly, or anything you'd like me to look in to while I'm here, please leave an answer below.

I'll also be in and out of [StopPress](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) (the chat room) all day answering questions and commenting on presentations.

I can also be contacted on Twitter ([@ericmann](https://twitter.com/#!/EricMann)).

Comment: Lots of good presentations today! I don't think I have any WPSE-specific questions to pass along.

Comment: Hand out all the swag! :D

Comment: So far, people are loving the stickers! :-) The rest gets handed out today.